# Comode compras con PHP Y MYSQL EN VEZ DE ELIMINAR AGREGA

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un proyecto en php y mysql pero cuando agrega al carrito si agrega pero solo agrega el id y la cantidad, mas no el nombre ni la descripcion tampoco elimina mas bien agrega

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Necesitamos el código del CRUD, formularios y posiblemente estructura de la BD, para poder ayudarte.